# Migrating from LiteSpeed to Apache special characters in image names 404

Tags: apache-2.4, url, encoding, litespeed

On my host running LiteSpeed, images with special characters in filenames like "é" work just fine.
When i migrate the site to my local development stacks, be them WAMP clones or even a Vagrant VM on Ubuntu, all running Apache, I get a 404.

What exactly is the setting that I need to use on Apache so it behaves like LiteSpeed in this regard?

Answer (score 0):

It is more likely an issue with file system, file name encoding issue. linux -> macosx.

Comment: I'm on Windows and this happens both on portable WAMP stacks that access the win filesystem directly and on a Vagrant VM that accesses the files via NFS.